# Can't install react-native-unimodules on React Native 0.60.3

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, podspec, podfile

Installed with `yarn install react-native-unimodules`

The next step in the instructions required me to edit my project Podfile. The necessary additions were [shown here](https://gist.github.com/sjchmiela/6c079f2173938a9a61a7c6f053c45000).

Here is my resultant Podfile

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
target 'MyProjectName' do
  # Pods for MyProjectName
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTImage',
  ]
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  use_unimodules!

  target 'MyProjectNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'MyProjectName-tvOS' do
  # Pods for MyProjectName-tvOS

  target 'MyProjectName-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

The next step is running `pod install`, which gives the following output/error:

```sh
$ pod install
Installing unimodules:
 expo-app-loader-provider@5.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-app-loader-provider/ios
 expo-constants@5.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-file-system@5.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
 expo-permissions@5.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios
 unimodules-camera-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios
 unimodules-constants-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios
 unimodules-core@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios
 unimodules-file-system-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios
 unimodules-font-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios
 unimodules-permissions-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-sensors-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@2.0.1 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `EXAppLoaderProvider` from `../node_modules/expo-app-loader-provider/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXConstants` from `../node_modules/expo-constants/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXFileSystem` from `../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXPermissions` from `../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios`
Fetching podspec for `React-Core` from `../node_modules/react-native/React`
Fetching podspec for `React-DevSupport` from `../node_modules/react-native/React`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTActionSheet` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTAnimation` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTBlob` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTImage` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTLinking` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTNetwork` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTSettings` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTText` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTVibration` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration`
Fetching podspec for `React-RCTWebSocket` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket`
Fetching podspec for `React-cxxreact` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact`
Fetching podspec for `React-fishhook` from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook`
Fetching podspec for `React-jsi` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi`
Fetching podspec for `React-jsiexecutor` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor`
Fetching podspec for `React-jsinspector` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector`
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native/`
Fetching podspec for `UMBarCodeScannerInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMCameraInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMConstantsInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMCore` from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMFaceDetectorInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMFileSystemInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMFontInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMImageLoaderInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMPermissionsInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMReactNativeAdapter` from `../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMSensorsInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `UMTaskManagerInterface` from `../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
  In Podfile:
    React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

Following the responses to a [Github issue regarding this exact error output](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25553#), I did a search of file contents for my entire project directory and did not get a hit for any place `React-Core` may be badly defined as `React/Core`.

This is my first time ever editing a Podfile, and I fear I may have fumbled something in the syntax.

Comment: Why is the phrase `use_native_modules!` added?

Comment: That was already there when I opened the `Podfile`. As I said, it was my first time ever editing it so I only added content as described at the gist the install instructions linked. I noticed theirs did not have that line (nor the `require_relative` directive for the `......native_modules` at the top of the Podfile. I don't know the implications of running `pod install` after removing either line, and I feared I'd cause more problems by doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React Native [changed a lot of things in 0.60](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60), one of them was to [split React podspec into separate podspecs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/2321b3f).

That means that `React` podspec no longer has any `subspecs`. The error you're getting is `React/Core`, which used to be a subspec, is no longer available (it's now imported separately). To fix the problem, remove the `subspecs` from your `Podfile`:

```rb
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
etc...
```

Note that many tutorials and documentation you'll find on the web include the `subspecs` definitions. That's how things were done in React Native <=0.59, and are no longer valid in 0.60.

Comment: because of this, in Xcode `Build Phases` > `Link Binary with Libraries` has no React libraries added by default. and when I add a library, I will get an error `React/RCTBridgeModule.h file not found` and I couldn't link `libReact.a` since it's nowhere to be found because of separate podspecs. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x `Link Binary with Libraries` is not being used anymore. The library you're adding should have a podspec file, then you can add it using something like `pod 'RNMyLibrary', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-my-library/ios'`. Most libraries have supported this for months (way before 0.60). If yours doesn't, you should raise an issue with the library creator.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `podspec` names changed: `React-Core` is not in sub folder it is in root folder. Here is my working pod file with `React-Native 0.61.3`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp

  pod 'RNDeviceInfo',         :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'FBLazyVector',         :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'RCTRequired',          :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety',        :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec',    :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'React-RCTVibration',   :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings',    :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText',        :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking',     :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTImage',       :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork',     :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation',   :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob',        :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-cxxreact',       :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi',            :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor',    :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector',    :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'React-CoreModules',    :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'ReactCommon',          :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon'
  pod 'React-Core',           :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'React',                :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog',             :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly',            :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```